# Can a string with variables be stored in array?

Tags: java

I would like to have an array that contains strings with variable, so the user will be able choose which sentence he wants and what will be the value of the variable.

For example, the array will contain:

```
arr[0] = "Hi " + name + ", Welcome"
arr[1] = "Happy Birthday " + name;
arr[2] = "You are " + name;
```

I want to get an array like this from a function, and then to print it with some name. 
For example:

```
String s = (a[0], "Joe")
```

So that `s` will be:

```
Hi Joe, Welcome
```

Is it possible?

Comment: no in that way. You can have instead a array of `Cheer` that print something depending on the input

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do:

```
String[] arr = new String[3];
arr[0] = "Hi %s, Welcome"
arr[1] = "Happy Birthday %s";
arr[2] = "You are %s";
```

Then

```
for (String s : arr) {
    System.out.printf(s + "%n", "Joe");
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Hi Joe, Welcome
Happy Birthday Joe
You are Joe
```

The printf uses the `java.util.Formatter` to allow insertion of variables into a String. The `%n` creates a new line within the Formatter

For more on this, please check out this relevant tutorial: [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Comment: Your code is not compilable. The `%s` phrases must be part of the string.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: dang, you're right! Thanks!! sloppy quick answer :(

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is there any option that s will be the full string (like in the printing result), so that I can use him to something else?

Comment: Ok, I found it: String s2 = String.format(a[0], "Joe");
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can define an interface to `Cheer` and implement each behavior like this

```
interface Cheer {
    String cheerTo(String name);
}

class Welcome implements Cheer {

    @Override
    public String cheerTo(String name) {
        return "Hi " + name + ", Welcome";
    }
}

class Birthday implements Cheer {

    @Override
    public String cheerTo(String name) {
        return "Happy Birthday " + name;
    }
}

class Whoim implements Cheer {

    @Override
    public String cheerTo(String name) {
        return "You are " + name;
    }
}
```

then you can use it like this

```
    Cheer[] array = new Cheer[3];
    array[0] = new Welcome();
    array[1] = new Birthday();
    array[2] = new Whoim();

    String s = array[0].cheerTo("Joe");
    String b = array[1].cheerTo("Sam");
    System.out.println(s); // prints:  Hi Joe, Welcome 
    System.out.println(b); // prints:  Happy Birthday Sam
```